# I am new to node.js and trying to figure out how asynchronous call back work

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code given below gives "one" "two" as output but not "three"

Can anybody explain me the reason why three is not being displayed in the output?

I have tried many approaches but still can't figure out what's going wrong.

```
const http=require('http');
const fs=require('fs');

function f1( ()=>{console.log("three");})
{
  console.log("two");
}

const server=http.createServer((req,res)=>{
  console.log("one");
  f1();


});


server.listen(9800);
```

Comment: I think this shouldn't compile: you are giving the value of an argument in the definition of f1. `()=>{console.log("three");}` is a given lambda function. It's like defining a function like this: `function f1( 'given string' )`. This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by xavier, this shouldn't compile only. One way you could try this is:

```
const IamCallBack = () => { console.log("three");};
function f1(callback) {
console.log("two");
callback();
}

f1(IamCallBack);
```

Comment: thnx a lot for your response

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use callbacks:

```
const http=require('http');
const fs=require('fs');

function f1(arg_string,callback)
{
      console.log(arg_string);
      callback("three");
}

const server=http.createServer((req,res)=>{
});


server.listen(9800);

console.log("one");
f1("two",function(cb_string){
    console.log(cb_string);
});
```

This would print:

```
one
two
three
```

First, "two" is given as an argument to `f1`, which prints it to the console.
Once the function is done, it calls the `callback` function.
We have defined the callback function as:

```
function(cb_string){
    console.log(cb_string);
}
```

This is supplied as the second argument when calling `f1`. Then once `f1` has finished running, it will call whatever function was supplied to it:

```
function f1(arg_string,callback)
{
      console.log(arg_string);
      callback("three"); //<--- whatever function you used to call it
}
```

When the callback function is executed, it goes outputs "three" because that's what `f1` gave back to your original caller:

```
console.log(cb_string);
```

Comment: thnxx a lot for your response

Comment: No problem @Jatin !